# Session Time out after refresh the page respective content is loading in java

Tags: java, session-timeout

i have tried sample sessiontime out options to my java application.. i have used below code in web.xml

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>5</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
```

For every 5 minutes application is getting sessiontime out correctly. But when i refresh the same page its get logged in automatically and displaying the respective content of the page.
I would like to have the login page even i refresh the page after session time out.

Please anyone advice me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Did you try removing the cookie when the session times out?

Comment: You need to check every request to your page is associated with a session. if not, just send it to the login page

Answer (score 0):

Use a filter or an interceptor to check the session validity for every request. If the session is invalid, proceed to login page, if not render the page requested. Plenty of articles are available to help you write any of the above.

Answer (score 0):

have you try checking the login session ?

```
System.out.println(request.getSession().getAttribute(yourUserSession));
```